# High number of Rx Overruns for particular port on switch

Tags: network-adapter, switch, mikrotik-swos

The switch is Mikrotik CSS326 and I'm concerned about errors in port n° 9 in this image :

[image]

23'428 Rx Overruns while other ports are much lower, including port n° 1 which is connected to the router.

According to this [What Are "Overruns" on a Serial Interface?](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/dial-access/asynchronous-connections/15286-serial-overruns.html) Rx Overruns happen when the port is receiving data at a higher speed than it can transfer them from the fifo buffer to the switch's shared memory.

So why could this happen. Is it a hardware problem at the network card of the PC connected to the port, or a software related (computer at port ° 2 also uses a particular software).

Comment: Have you tried updating the firmware? What type of cable is on this port? What's the model of the nic that's attached to it? You may want to try jperf or iperf across this switch port, clear the counters and see if it only happens under certain conditions. (Traffic in one direction but not the other, under heavy load etc)

Comment: I updated the switch' firmware to the latest version (2.8) and since then there have been only 200 RxOverruns for the computer on that particular port. There are still 36'317 overruns on another computer though, and 69'275 between the two switches which are connected with a 50cm cat5e patch cord. I dont think it's hardware related, and it does happen in one direction, ie when the port is receiving packets.